# Python access widgets of parent class in Qthread

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

I want to access the parent class widgets in the `QThread` class

This line gives hangs GUI "Example().setWindowTitle("Window")"

How can I do that?

```
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.myclass2 = myclass2()
        self.myclass2.start()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Icon')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('web.png'))
        self.show()


class myclass2(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myclass2, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(.1)
            print(" in thread \n")
            Example().setWindowTitle("Window")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must understand the following expression:

```
Example().setWindowTitle("Window")
```

it is equivalent to:

```
obj = Example()
obj.setWindowTitle("Window")
```

That is, you are creating another Example object other than `ex = Example()`, and that object is creating another `myclass2` object, and that other `myclass2` object is creating another Example, and an infinite loop is clearly being created.

---

Another thing that in the future could cause you problems is to establish the same name for different things, although in this case it is not a problem but in future occasions it could bring you problems, the code to which I refer is:

```
self.myclass2 = myclass2()
```

For example, it is recommended that classes should start with capital letters.

---

Another error that is valid only in Qt is that the GUI can not be created or manipulated in a thread other than the main thread. So you can not change the title directly in the other thread but there are 2 methods:

### 1. `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(...)`

But for this we must pass the GUI through a property:

```
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.myclass2 = MyClass()
        self.myclass2.gui = self
        self.myclass2.start()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Icon')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('web.png'))
        self.show()


class MyClass(QThread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(.1)
            print(" in thread \n")
            QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self.gui, "setWindowTitle", Qt.QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(str, "Window"))
```

### 2. signals & slots

```
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.myclass2 = MyClass()
        self.myclass2.titleChanged.connect(self.setWindowTitle)
        self.myclass2.start()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Icon')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('web.png'))
        self.show()


class MyClass(QThread):
    titleChanged = pyqtSignal(str)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(.1)
            print(" in thread \n")
            self.titleChanged.emit("Window")
```

**PLUS:**

You should not modify the GUI from the thread directly but send the data through a signal:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Example(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        lay.addWidget(le)
        self.myclass2 = MyClass()
        self.myclass2.titleChanged.connect(self.setWindowTitle)
        self.myclass2.infoChanged.connect(le.setText) # <-- connect signal
        self.myclass2.start()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Icon')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('web.png'))
        self.show()


class MyClass(QtCore.QThread):
    titleChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    infoChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str) # <-- create signal

    def run(self):
        counter = 0
        while True:
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(100)
            print(" in thread \n")
            self.titleChanged.emit("Window")
            self.infoChanged.emit("{}".format(counter)) # <-- emit signal
            counter += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Actually, i want to use the new thread to update the widgets of the class, is it possible through the basic python thread

Comment: Actually , i want to know that the new thread which is created by Class Example, in this thread i want to run a while loop and this loop has to update a lineEdit at a fix interval

Comment: I am confused how to get that access to modify the linedit of GUI in this new thread

Comment: @aditya I have added an example of how you should update the QLineEdit from another thread, read my answer, understand it, practice it, modify it. If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank the work I have taken to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i was confused but thanks for guiding me

Comment: @ellyanesc Can you show me the same for qtableWidget? how can i setitem from the new thread to this widget?

Comment: @aditya only change `self.myclass2.infoChanged.connect(le.setText)` to `self.myclass2.infoChanged.connect(your_tablewidget.item(0, 0).setText)`

Comment: @ellyanesc but this is only for one cell block , i have some multiple blocks. is their any way i can set the item index in thread and then set the text?