# PyQt5, QThread: How to keep GUI responsive while running non-loop function in thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, qthread

What I have so far is basically this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import time

class WorkerThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, app, ml, parent=None):
        self.p = app
        self.ml = ml
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def run(self):
        self.ml()

class HelperClassForGUI:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.p = app

    def mainFunc(self):
        self.thread = WorkerThread(self.p, SomeHeavyFunction)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.done)
        self.thread.start()

    def done(self):
        ...
```

So I have a function (the 'SomeHeavyFunction') from an external library (so I have no control over it) which, if called normally, takes a few seconds to complete and thus freezes the GUI, so I wanted to use a thread to keep the GUI responsive in the meanwhile.

Problem is, the app still freezes. The 'done()' function is executed as it should, so I can assume that a thread with the function was actually started terminated properly, but the desired effect doesn't show up.

For testing, instead of the actual 'SomeHeavyFunction', I tried a function like this:

```
def func(self):
    self.idx = 0
    while self.idx < 100:
        if (self.idx % 3 == 0):
            self.p.statusBar.showMessage('Calculating ..')
        elif (self.idx % 3 == 1):
            self.p.statusBar.showMessage('Calculating. .')
        elif (self.idx % 3 == 2):
            self.p.statusBar.showMessage('Calculating.. ')
        self.idx += 1
        time.sleep(1)
```

With this, the GUI stays responsive, but here I have a different issue that the GUI often crashes if I try to interact with the GUI too much during the thread (e.g., trying to make larger tooltips show up) or if I decrease the waiting time from 1 second to 0.1 seconds.

So, my question is: What am I missing? What do I need to do so that the GUI will stay responsive and won't crash? As stated above, I have no access to the SomeHeavyFunction, I can just call it, but not split it up to loopable pieces or something like that (what I saw from most tutorials is that they would call 'processEvents' to keep the GUI responsive and their threads were usually some kind of simple loop, I can't really apply that to my problem).

EDIT: Emphasis is on 'function that is NOT a loop'. I have no control over SomeHeavyFunction(). It does NOT consist for a loop and I don't have any way to send any periodic signals from within it. What I need is that SomeHeavyFunction() is started in some (asynchronous?) thread which can take as long as it needs, as long as the GUI stays responsive in the mean time. So, basically a 'background' thread.

Comment: Does func() reproduce the behavior of SomeHeavyFunction() ?, that is, if it solves func() SomeHeavyFunction() will be solved. On the other hand the GUI can not be updated directly in another thread, for this you must use signals or the QMetaObject. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52178004/python-access-widgets-of-parent-class-in-qthread/52178857#52178857

Comment: No, func() and SomeHeavyFunction() aren't really similar, apart from the fact that both functions take few seconds to complete. func() was just something I tried to see what the behaviour would be if I used a function which mainly consists of a big loop.
EDIT: Had a look at QMetaObject and I don't understand it, sorry. I also don't understand how that 'setWindowTitle' is related to my problem.

Comment: is that my question or problem is that if you give a solution to fun this will not be the solution to your real problem and then probably you will change your question and I probably propose another solution and you change, ..., and that would be annoying , for that reason I recommend that you provide a [mcve] of your real problem, that is to say make it fun very close to someheavyfunction. On the other hand processEvents is a bad practice, forget it, many times they partially hide the problem, but the problem will continue to persist.

Comment: Do the details of SomeHeavyFunction really matter? If possible, it would be great to know a general solution to this problem which would work for any SomeHeavyFunction... in case that doesn't work: SomeHeavyFunction() consists mainly of the fit()-function of various scikit learn models, for example, DecisionTree.
EDIT: I also have a little trouble understanding the first part of your comment... what I basically need is a general solution that works for starting a performance-intensive thread for a PyQt5 GUI which will keep the GUI responsive and not cause crashes... just that.

Comment: @eyllanesc That doesn't answer anything though... as I said, I need a solution for a thread that is NOT executed in a loop. How will signals help if I don't have a loop from where I can send signals periodically?

Comment: the loop is irrelevant, if the loop does not exist even the signals should work